# "Vertical and linear units in the X,Y, and Z coordinate systems are not the same" error in a task process

Tags: coordinate-system, las, vertical-transformation, lasd

I am having a CS issue for my LASD dataset. I'm trying to run a tool in ArcGIS Pro that will analyze my LiDAR dataset (about 100 tiles) and create tree points based on the clustering of classified vegetation points. Here's a picture of the error:
[image]

And here's a picture of the spatial reference information of the LAS tile (they're all the same):
[image]

I will confess to struggling with understanding coordinate reference systems and how to transform them to match better. To me, it looks like all the units are in feet for the Projected CS, the Geographic CS, and the vertical CS. There's something big I'm missing -- What do I need to know so I can intuit what I need to do to not run into situations like this? Is there something that doesn't jive between NAVD88 and NAD83? Where should I be looking to see that the 'vertical and linear units' aren't the same?

Comment: Hmmm, I agree with you that the units match. However, the VCS is 'custom' and maybe that's throwing off the tool. Maybe try redefining the vertical coordinate system to 6360.  It's the same definition; just omits the info about Geoid12B.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at are the expected units, not necessarily what your data is. Create X Y and Z columns in your attribute table and Calculate Geometry the x y and z coordinates into the columns so you can see your actual values.